# jQuery click event in loop broken by float attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add click event handlers to a bunch of dynamically generated divs using jQuery using code as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var testdiv = document.createElement('div');
    testdiv.innerHTML = 'test' + i;
    testdiv.id = 'test' + i;

    var nestingdiv = document.createElement('div');
    nestingdiv.classList.add('nestingdiv');
    nestingdiv.appendChild(testdiv);

    setTestClickHandler(i);
end

function setTestClickHandler(i) {
    $('#test' + i).click(function() {
        alert(i);
    });
```

This works perfectly normally, but as soon as I add a float parameter to the `.nestingdiv` class like this:

```
.nestingdiv { float:left; }
```

The click handler no longer triggers (tested on Firefox and Chrome). Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case or how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: I would add a background colour property to your divs, eg. div { background-color: red; } and observe the page - you'll probably find your divs are in a different place / shape to what you expect!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how this can work properly at all when you are not connecting these elements to DOM tree. Try to add the `nestingdiv` to the existing and living tree using `document.body.appendChild(nestingdiv)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't your JavaScript, it's your CSS. In other words, the "click" handlers are just fine. When the only nested element is floating, the parent element loses it's "structure" (for lack of a better word) and collapses.  It's still there, but it's now 1px high.

Solution:
    http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Alternative solution:
    http://thinkvitamin.com/design/everything-you-know-about-clearfix-is-wrong/

Comment: Thanks so much - that's fantastic! I think my css is a bit rusty, as I remember battling with clearing floats before, but was sure it was an event handler problem so overlooked this.